# how to shake a div vertically using JQuery shake

Tags: jquery

I use this code to shake a div

```
$(".target").effect( "shake", 
      {times:4}, 1000 );
```

Is it possible to shake vertically and also set height of shake

Comment: Does this help:- http://jsfiddle.net/HjFUK/87/ ??

Comment: vertically shake could be applied with: `$(".target").effect('bounce')`

Comment: @ABFORCE Not necessarily as the Shake Effect supports also vertical movements.

Comment: @Itay: you're right but this is a shortcut

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the options called `direction` and `distance` as shown in the [Shake Effect API](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/).

```
$(".target").effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 4, distance: 10}, 1000 );
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/XHZmr/)

---

## Shake Effect API

> ## direction (default: "left")
>
> **Type:** String A value of "left" or "right"
> will shake the element horizontally, and a value of "up" or "down"
> will shake the element vertically. The value specifies which direction
> the element should move along the axis for the first step of the
> effect.
>
> ## distance (default: 20)
>
> **Type:** Number
> Distance to shake.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it using simple jQuery and JavaScript knowledge:
`setInterval`:

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    $el = $(this);
    setInterval(function(){ 
        if ($el.hasClass('shake')) {
            $el.removeClass('shake');
        } else {
            $el.addClass('shake');
        };  
    }, 320);
};

$('.button').shake();
```

Adding and removing a class uses less resources than modifying properties in DOM. And we can also take advantage of CSS transitions applied to our `.button`:

```
.button {  margin-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin-top 300ms ease-out;
    transition: margin-top 300ms ease-out; }
.button.shake { margin-top: 15px; }
```

Final note, make sure your `.button` element is placed in a div with `position: absolute` so it doesn't push around everything below it.

Answer (score 3):

A/ pure CSS, no JS dependency - shake on mouse hover:

```
.target:hover{
  animation: shake 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  75% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
```

B/ controlling with jQuery - start shaking on `click`, stop on `mouseout`:

```
$(".target").on("click", function(){
    $(this).css({
        'animation' : 'shake 0.5s',
        'animation-iteration-count' : 'infinite'
    });
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).css({
        'animation' : '',
        'animation-iteration-count' : ''
    });
})
```

Comment: This is Great! I used it to apply to my filter button once the user chose a filter to apply to the search to bring their attention to which button to click to perform the search. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Jquery or CSS

1.**jQuery** using this plugin:

http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

2.**CSS**

http://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQueryUI is required and i don't want to include the library, here is a solution using underscore (for the ones using underscore)

```
_(4).times(function(n){
    _.delay(function(){
        $("element").css("margin-left", (((n+1)%2)*5)+"px");
    }, n*70);
});
```